# Liferay: assigning permissions to action

Tags: security, permissions, liferay

I have a portlet developed with Liferay 6.1.1 which shows the details of a training course, and shows a "Sign up to this course" button.

I would like to show the button in all cases, but only allow to sign up if the user is logged in. Otherwise, it should show the login form and if successful, automatically sign the user up to that course.

For that, I thought it would be wise to delegate the permission control to Liferay, which to my knowledge already performs the desired behavior (if you try to enter something thats out of limits as a guest, you are prompted with the login form, then if successful you are returned to the requested resource).

The "Sign up" is implemented as an Action in my portlet, so how can I tell Liferay that that speficic action (and only that action) should be exclusive to registered members **with a certain role**?

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is probably not the right place to get a full answer about the inner features of how to implement Liferay's permission system, however, the documentation has [a chapter about the implementation](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/learning-paths/mvc/-/knowledge_base/6-2/setting-permissions) of your own plugin with Liferay's Permissions. I'm linking the 6.2 version, but I'm not aware of breaking changes between the two versions.

However, you should update to a version that has a few more fixes than yours - at least be on the latest available 6.1 x version, though even that has not seen any more updates for a long time (in favor of 6.2)